# Convert Google Drive URI to Google Cloud Storage URI?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I am using a Google API that wants files to be in Google Cloud Storage. However I have my files in Google Drive. Is there any known way to convert Google Drive URI:s to Google Cloud Storage URI:s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way around this, unless you can file a feature request for Google through https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do what you're asking, because Drive and GCS have separate APIs. You would need to copy files from Drive to GCS (using each system's API) and use the GCS URI.

Comment: Yes, but that is up to Google, of course. I wondered if there is any way around this restriction.